# How can I check multiple extensions in arcpy and print an interesting statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to check if three extensions are available in arcpy. How can I return a statement listing the extensions that are available?

```
import arcpy

if arcpy.CheckExtension("3D, Network, Spatial") == "Available":
print "These extensions are available.."
else:
    raise LicenseError

except LicenseError:
   print("license is unavailable")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following:

```
availLicense = []

if arcpy.CheckExtension("3D") == "Available":
    availLicense.append("ArcGIS 3D Analyst")
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Network") == "Available":
    availLicense.append("ArcGIS Network Analyst")
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    availLicense.append("ArcGIS Spatial Analyst")

print "The following extensions are available: " + str(availLicense).strip('[]')
```

Output looks like this:

The following extensions are available: 'ArcGIS 3D Analyst', 'ArcGIS Network Analyst', 'ArcGIS Spatial Analyst'

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[arcgis](/questions/tagged/arcgis)[arcpy](/questions/tagged/arcpy)

Comment: Thanks, you're the best :D

Answer (score 2):

You can check them one by one in a for loop, put the available ones in a list, and then print them. You can also check and print the ones that are unavailable using the same method.